# Issue with my website url

Tags: javascript, php, html

obiventures.com is my website, when I open this site I found http://obiventures.com/OBI1.0/home.html this URL how to remove/hide this **OBI1.0/home.html** from website URL? please help me.

Comment: You have a redirect. But this doesn't help anyone debug your issue without any code.

Comment: A simple google search provided lots of resources. Here is the first thing I got: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and where you are stuck along with examples of your code because if you havent even started google is a better resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the home.html file in to the start directory, in other words not in any folders or just out of the OBI1.0 folder, and rename it index.html. Then you can go to [obiventures.com](http://obiventures.com/) / http://obiventures.com / http://obiventures.com/ and it will be there.
Oh, and nice website by the way.